# Checking Query String for "{" or "}"

Tags: php

Here is what I currently have working:

```
$one = (isset($_GET["onen"]) && $_GET["onen"] !== "{stn}") && (isset($_GET["onec"]) && $_GET["onec"] !== "{cid}");
```

what this does is checks the url for `?onen` and it also makes sure `?onen` does not have a value of `{stn}`.  It does the same thing for `?onec` and `{cid}`

What I would like to do, is check the query string to make sure `{` and `}` are **NOWHERE** to be found in the string for `onen` and `onec` so even if the string ends up being `st{n}` i would like to be able to detect that `{` is there

how would I add this functionality to the `$one` variable?

**EDIT**
I tried this:

```
$one = (isset($_GET["onen"]) && $_GET["onen"] !== "{stn}") && strpos('{', $_GET['onen']) && strpos('}', $_GET['onen']) !== FALSE && (isset($_GET["onec"]) && $_GET["onec"] !== "{cid}") && strpos('{', $_GET['onec']) && strpos('}', $_GET['onec']) !== FALSE;
```

the strpos stops the rest of the code from working even without `{` or `}` being anywhere in the string

**EDIT #2:**

here is the full php:

```
$one = (isset($_GET["onen"]) && $_GET["onen"] !== "{stn}") 
        && strpos('{', $_GET['onen']) !== FALSE && strpos('}', $_GET['onen']) !== FALSE 
        && (isset($_GET["onec"]) && $_GET["onec"] !== "{cid}")
        && strpos('{', $_GET['onec']) !== FALSE && strpos('}', $_GET['onec']) !== FALSE;

if( $one ) {

    $value = "yes";


}else{
    $value = "no";

}?>

<?php echo $value ?>
```

after adding strpos, even without `{` or `}` in the string, I still get a value of "no" when it should be "yes" like it was before

Just so I'm understood, i also need this to work if there is only `{` or only `}` in the string.. doesnt have to be both in the string

Comment: `strpos('{', $_GET['onen']) !== FALSE`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for that.

These check if a { is found.

```
strpos('{', $_GET['onen']) !== FALSE
```

And

```
strpos('{', $_GET['onec']) !== FALSE
```

**UPDATE**

```
$one = (isset($_GET["onen"]) && $_GET["onen"] !== "{stn}") 
        && strpos('{', $_GET['onen']) !== FALSE && strpos('}', $_GET['onen']) !== FALSE 
        && (isset($_GET["onec"]) && $_GET["onec"] !== "{cid}")
        && strpos('{', $_GET['onec']) !== FALSE && strpos('}', $_GET['onec']) !== FALSE;
```

Comment: how would I add this to my current code example? and since i want to do it both for `{` and `}` would it be `strpos('{', $_GET['onen']) && strpos('}', $_GET['onen']) !== FALSE` ?

Comment: Not quite, it would be strpos('{', $_GET['onen']) !== FALSE && strpos('}', $_GET['onen']) !== FALSE

Comment: Have a try yourself and update your answer if you get stuck and I will have a look at it

Comment: @david-james i updated the original post after testing.. i added the strpos but nothing works after it was added

Comment: You did the same as you did in the last comment, missing out the !== FALSE from the first strpos. See my updated answer.

Comment: I edited the main post with the full php code.. still getting the wrong value even without "{" and "}" in the url. thankss for the help so far!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62341/discussion-between-joe-bobby-and-david-jones).

Answer (score 0):

You can either check with strpos as David suggested or use

```
preg_match('#{.*?\}#', $_GET['onen'])
```

to check if it's exactly {anyword}

Fiddle: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2929489c07e181ec46a0587e0e6c80f2794d5443

second option is to check only for { or }

```
preg_match('#({|})#', $_GET['onen'])
```

Fiddle: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8136b2e71828b926d4d917b90651e9f0be07b17c

Comment: yep :) It will work with anything that contains {anyword} so can be asdfasdf{word} or {word} or {word}adfasdf strings.

Comment: ok and it will also work if only `{` or `}` are present or does it hve to be both ?

Comment: I've attached fiddle check it :) and you'll understand

Comment: i updated the fiddle, it seems it doesnt work with only '{' or only '}' http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad9bde162abb61f3860b69b7af11e16b4812715d

Comment: no it works with both :) if want check only {} you can use `preg_match('#({|})#', $t)` check http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8136b2e71828b926d4d917b90651e9f0be07b17c

Comment: shouldnt the examples 3, 4, 5, end up with `1` when tested in the fiddle?

Comment: If you test it against the second regex then it'll end up with 1

Answer (score 0):

Easy with regex, this

```
$onen = isset($_GET["onen"]) ? $_GET["onen"] :"";
$onec = isset($_GET["onec"]) ? $_GET["onenc"] :"";

$pattern = '/{.+}/U';

if( preg_match($pattern, $onen) || preg_match($pattern, $onec)){
    echo "one or both has {}";
    $one=false;
}else{
    $one=true;
}
```

1. Will match "dasd{as}das" or "{a}" and similar
2. will not match "asdas d}asd" "dasd}asd{" and similar